# Is there anyway to Display "Business Hours" on "User's Pagelayout". I have created different Business Hours for different Time zones

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created different Business Hours for Users in different Time zones. But I cannot display Business Hours on "Users Page-layout". On User's Object "Lookup relationship" is not available. Under "Buttons and Links", there is no "create action" option. By creating Buttons or Custom Links, "Business Hour" do appears on User's Detail page under Custom links, but nothing then happens. Its like inactive there.

How can I make Business Hours display on User's Pagelayout as a Picklist?